# Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I have a complex TypeScript type and I want to handle it in a function, simply like this:

```js
type T = { a: number } | { b: number }

function func(k: 'a' | 'b', v: number) {
    // error appear below
    const t: T = { [k]: v }
    console.log(t);
}
```

I got an error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  Property 'b' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: number; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic key setting by itself loses the typing, which can be prevented by an explicit type using some other function:

```
function put<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, value: V): {[P in K]: V};
function put<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, value: V) {
  return {[key]: value};
}
```

Usage:

```
function func(k: "a" | "b", v: number) {
  const t: T = put(k, v); // no error
  console.log(t);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBDAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAXygB9l8McDiSBuAKCYDNtMBjYASwHtMUMNmAAeANJQIAD2ARMAEwDOUAApE+kIqHEQQAGigA1AHwAKANZ6M4wwDcUAG2wQMRgJQYkAbVVQeguIAum6MbBzc-ILCYpIycooq6prEOnqGppbWULZQDs6uxu7ITFBQRBDA2ESCPlYgIXlOLmEkLOxcvAJQHZyWGABEKAMUUAP4A-Y0eIRExUilUJwCSsBQwBhwiDGW9u7MZcuYSnyOEAB0jnwA5mbA+0xtQA)